# Problems with displaying JSON data I got from a server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm new to JSON/AJAX and
I've some problems with displaying data out of a JSON-object I've got from a server..
The url "http://localhost:8387/rest/resourcestatus.json" represents this object, which I would like to display via HTML/Javascript.. This object stores some monitoring information:

> ```
> {"groupStatus":[
>
> {"id":"AL Process","time":1332755316976,"level":0,"warningIds":[],"errorIds":[]},
> {"id":"AL:instance1","time":1332919465317,"level":0,"warningIds":[],"errorIds":[]},
> {"id":"AL:instance2","time":1332919465317,"level":1,"warningIds":["documentarea.locked"],"errorIds":[]},
> {"id":"SL","time":1331208543687,"level":0,"warningIds":[],"errorIds":[]}
>
> ]}
> ```

Since the requested url is different from my domain I can't create a typical XMLHttpRequest.. So I found out that there's an AJAX cross-domain request which can be realised via jQuerys "getJSON()" method.

I want to display the **ids** and their **level** in a table.

Any solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The callback function of [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) contains the result of the AJAX call in it's argument.

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8387/rest/resourcestatus.json', function(data) {
    $(data.groupStatus).each(function() {
        // do something with $(this).id
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and how can id and level now be displayed? like this way? $('#content').append('<p>ID: ' + $(this).id+ '</p>');

Answer (score 0):

i think you are referring to [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). see [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) Ex:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8387/rest/resourcestatus.json';    
$.getJSON(url+'?callback=?', function(data) 
{
    //data is 
    /*{
        "groupStatus":
        [
            {"id":"AL Process","time":1332755316976,"level":0,"warningIds":[],"errorIds":[]},
            {"id":"AL:instance1","time":1332919465317,"level":0,"warningIds":[],"errorIds":[]},
            {"id":"AL:instance2","time":1332919465317,"level":1,"warningIds":["documentarea.locked"],"errorIds":[]},
            {"id":"SL","time":1331208543687,"level":0,"warningIds":[],"errorIds":[]}
        ]
    }*/
});
```

on the server side you will need to wrap the response into a JavaScript function:  `response = Request["callback"] +"("+ response+")";`

the result will look like this:

```
?({"groupStatus":[{"id":"AL ....})
```

So the browser will actually load a valid java script code.